# Criar um Web Api que chame outro Web Api

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

Criei um Web Api aqui no meu trabalho pra ser consumido por meu projeto Xamarin Forms. **Está funcionando 100% e sem problemas...**
Aí fui informado que na verdade aqui se utiliza 2 web api´s por segurança. Ou seja, terei que criar um Web Api ("frontend") com acesso externo, que funcionaria como um porteiro, passando as chamadas para outro Web Api ("backend") e este, somente este, tem acesso ao BD e só aceita internamente. 
Como sou iniciante e tomei uma surra pra conseguir construir esse Web Api e ele funcionar, gostaria de uma ajuda em como fazer isso.
Eu teria que chamar o WebApi 1 e ele irá transportar os valores digitados pelo usuário até o Web Api 2... este por sua vez terá as chamadas de banco de dados e todos os controllers...após a consulta é que não entendi o que fazer, pois os dados são cuspidos no Json e boa parte eu consegui fazer funcionar na marra pesquisando.

Meu código no Xamarin:

```
ApiCall apiCall = new ApiCall();

                apiCall.GetResponse<List<Envolvido>>("nomes", "Envolvidos", nomepesquisa, nomemae, nomepai, dtnasc, nrg, ncpf).ContinueWith(t =>
               {
                   //Aqui verificamos se houve problema ne requisição
                   if (t.IsFaulted)
                   {
                       Debug.WriteLine(t.Exception.Message);
                       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                       {
                           DisplayAlert("Falha", "Ocorreu um erro na Requisição :(", "Ok");
                           //IsBusy = false;
                       });
                   }
                   //Aqui verificamos se a requisição foi cancelada por algum Motivo
                   else if (t.IsCanceled)
                   {
                       Debug.WriteLine("Requisição cancelada");

                       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                       {
                           DisplayAlert("Cancela", "Requisição Cancelada :O", "Ok");
                           //IsBusy = false;

                       });
                   }

                   //Caso a requisição ocorra sem problemas, cairemos aqui
                   else
                   {
                       //Se Chegarmos aqui, está tudo ok, agora itemos tratar nossa Lista
                       //Aqui Usaremos a Thread Principal, ou seja, a que possui as references da UI
                       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                          {
                              //IsBusy = false;
                              ListaDados.ItemsSource = t.Result;
                              var count = ListaDados.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().Count();
                              if (count == 0)
                              {
                                  DisplayAlert("Cancela", "Não há dados retornados.", "Ok");
                              }
                              else
                                  Navigation.PushAsync(new ResultadosBuscados(ListaDados.ItemsSource));
                          });

                   }
```

parte do meu ApiCall que chama o Web Api:

```
public class ApiCall
    {
        static readonly string ApiUrl = "http://Localhost:1762/api/{0}/{1}?nomePesquisa={2}&nomeMae={3}&nomePai={4}&dtNasc={5}&nrg={6}&ncpf={7}";

            public async Task<T> GetResponse<T>(string controller, string method, string nomepesquisa, 
            string nomemae, string nomepai, string dtnasc, string nrg, string ncpf) where T : class
        {
            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();


            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            var urllink = string.Format(ApiUrl, controller, method, nomepesquisa, nomemae, nomepai, dtnasc, nrg, ncpf);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(urllink);

            //Lê a string retornada
            var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                return null;

            //Converte o resultado Json para uma Classe utilizando as Libs do Newtonsoft.Json
            var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonResult);
            return rootobject;
        }
}
```

Meu controller code no Web Api:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/nomes")]
    public class NomesController : ApiController
    {
        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            string MeuConnString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION ="
                + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx)(PORT = xxx))"
                + "(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(service_name = xxx)));"
                + "User Id = xxx; Password=xxx";
            return MeuConnString;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Envolvidos")]
        public IEnumerable<Envolvido> GetEnvolv(string nomePesquisa, string nomeMae, string nomePai, string dtnasc
            , string nRG, string nCPF)
        {

            DataSet lretorno = new DataSet();

            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                OracleDataReader reader = null;
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd = new OracleCommand("MOBILE.XAPIMAND.BUSCAPOSCANDIDOSPF", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //variáveis entrada            
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivnome",nomePesquisa));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivmae", nomeMae));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivpai", nomePai));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivdatanasc", dtnasc));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivrg", nRG));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("icpf", nCPF));
                //variáveis de saida          
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("oretorno", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("qretorno", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                //CRIO A LISTA
                lretorno.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "BUSCAPOSSIVEISCANDIDATOSPF");
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();


                //CARREGO O DATASET E TRANSFORMO PARA IENUMERABLE E RETORNO SEUS VALORES PRO JSON
                return lretorno.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Envolvido
                {
                    SUSPID = Convert.ToInt32(row["SUSPID"]),
                    IVNOME = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPNOME"]),
                    IVMAE = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPMAE"]),
                    IVPAI = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPPAI"]),
                    IVDATANASC = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPDATANASC"]).Replace(" 00:00:00", ""),
                    IVRG = Convert.ToString(row["RG"]),
                    ICPF = Convert.ToString(row["CPF"]),
                    MANDADO = Convert.ToInt16(row["TEMMANDADO"]),
                    OCORRENCIA = Convert.ToInt16(row["TEMOCORRENCIA"]),

                });


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Qual o extra de segurança em ter duas API's?

Comment: @jbueno o 1º Web Api ("front") é conectado externamente... este se conecta ao 2º ("back"), que é conectado somente internamente...ou seja, se uma pessoa tentar acessar o BD de fora da rede, teoricamente, não consegue acesso.

Comment: @jbueno e Marcelo, eu tenho serias duvidas sobre este modelo de segurança, até por que o simples fato de fazer uma requisição ao banco de dados não deve expor o Banco de Dados. agora digamos que a WebAPI 1 tenha um serio problema de segurança que permita à um hack tomar o controle do servidor, neste caso ele vai está dentro da sua rede e terá acesso à WebAPI 2. E por fim, existem situações que é valido ter dois serviços, mas o segundo serviço normalmente WCF e possivelmente teria um binding nettcp e um sistema de autenticação mais restritivo.

Comment: @TobyMosque Concordo em partes.... aqui no meu trabalho essa é a estrutura pra tudo! Esse Mobile é o 1ª e de teste, mas pediram pra eu seguir a arquitetura quando fizesse. Só que como sou iniciante, ta dificil.
Na minha ApiCall eu tenho a chamada da URL usando System.Net.Http.HttpClient() e depois entro no controller... ou seja, agora, nesse Web Api "porteiro" eu terei que ter outra chamada de URL pro 2º Web Api e além disso, passar os parâmetros, retornando o dataset do 2ª Web Api...
Confusão na minha cabeça.
Queria que alguem desse um exemplo como seria, utilizando esse meu Código.

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes neste caso você não deveria ter duas WebAPI, você deveria ter um serviço WCF usando NetPeerTcpBinding com segurança ponto a ponto, apenas lembre-se de configurar as mensagens usando MTOM encoding.

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes Qual é a sua dúvida, realmente?

Comment: @Randrade Minha dúvida é sobre o que utilizar. Criei o Web Api pra consumir os dados do BD Oracle e está funcionando. Aí então fui informado que aqui na verdade não poderia usar essa arquitetura. Que eles usam um servidor para acesso externo e outro que só recebe acesso interno e estes se comunicam. Minha dúvida é como fazer essa comunicação...pensei em 2 Web Api´s, mas sou iniciante e não tenho muito conhecimento. Muito do que falaram aqui, não faço a minima do que seja rsrsrs.

Comment: Uma dica pro pessoal da sua empresa, usem o API Gateway pattern, (BFF - Backend for frontend). reduz. complexidade com esse porteiro aí, e deixa mais usável para a próxima alma que entrar nesse time :)

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, duas `WebAPI`s não é mais seguro que apenas uma, esta abordagem não vai proteger o seu sistema de um ataque, tais como `MITM`, `Sql Injection` ou qual quer outro ataque que você venha a imaginar.

Se o seu medo é que uma eventual falha grave dê o controle do servidor com à `WebAPI 1` à algum hacker, neste caso ele terá acesso total a maquina e a sua rede, então ele conseguiria acessar toda a sua estrutura.

Agora vamos à outro problema, `Session`, todos os acessos na segunda `WebAPI` serão realizados pelo mesmo usuário, então não terá uma `Session` por usuário e terá de utilizar um `workaround` (que possivelmente vai envolver em utilizar o `Cache` e adicionar o `SessionID` como um `Header` em todas as requisições).

Ainda temos um segundo problema um pouco mais grave, Autenticação e Autorização, como à sua segunda `WebAPI` vai saber se o usuário que fez a requisição a primeira `WebAPI` tem acesso. Em resumo você não poderá utilizar o `ASP.NET Identity` e terá de implementar um solução própria.

Um outro problema envolve transações, digamos que uma requisição da `WebAPI 1` precise realizar duas chamadas distintas à `WebAPI 2`, como você fará um rollback da primeira se a segunda dê errado? um `TransactionScope` faz falta né?

Mas ainda assim, um sistema com múltiplas camadas ainda tem a sua finalidade, pode ser que eu queira fazer uma camada de apresentação usando `AngularJS + WebAPI`, e outros sistemas que precisam consumir este serviço e algum deles não possa fazer uma requisição `http`.

Neste caso você vai precisar de um serviço WCF que ofereça um ou mais `binding`s que sejam apropriados para as aplicações que estejam consumindo o mesmo. o `binding` que oferece mais segurança para a comunicação entre duas aplicações feitas em `.NET` é `NetPeerTcpBinding`... aqui segue um exemplo.: [Peer-to-Peer Programming with WCF and .NET Framework 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx).

Lembrando que um serviço em `WCF` permite que você passe uma transação para ele, então você pode criar um `TransactionScope` na `WebAPI`, fazer n chamadas ao `serviço` e fazer um `rollback` com segurança se necessário.

E para consumir um serviço WCF, basta você adicionar uma `Service Reference`, o `Visual Studio` vai ter todo o trabalho de criar as classes de `proxy`, controlar abertura de canais, envio das mensagens, etc...

Agora você pode me perguntar por que não utilizar o `webHttpBinding` no `WCF` e utilizar uma `WebAPI` como interface para a `Web`? o primeiro ponto é a concorrência, a `Async WebAPI` consegue gerir muito melhor um cenário com múltiplas conexões, o outro ponto é quanto as opções de configuração, você terá um leque maior com à `WebAPI`.

Comment: Gostei da resposta, apesar de não ter entendido a pergunta. xD

Comment: Só uma coisa. Teoricamente, você consegue usar o Identity com esse modelo sim, mas terá uma trabalho maior em ter que passar o usuário para a segunda API manualmente.

Comment: @Randrade verdade, mais ainda acho que seja uma complexidade adicional que não trás nenhum ganho real.

Comment: Concordo plenamente. Só comentei porque na sua resposta fala que teria que desenvolver sua própria forma. Dessa forma dá a entender que não é possível usar, e não que não é viável.

Comment: @TobyMosque Aqui não tem o perigo do TransactionScope ... O service reference é uma opção. Meu problema é ser leigo e iniciante no assunto. A Infraestrutura daqui não é voltada pro Mobile. Estou querendo saber o que usar pra poder me aprofundar.